# Getting Error 150: C++ feature not enabled during compilation

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to call a C++ function from a C file for which I have declared the function in the .h file as :

File a.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif

EXTERNC void func();
#undef EXTERNC
```

The definition of the function func() is present in the a.cpp file.

I have a b.c file from where I want to call the function func(). I have included the a.h file in b.c and called the function func() normally. But during compilation I am getting the following error:

Compiling b.c
a.h(192) : error 150: 0: C++ feature not enabled.

Can someone help me resolve this error.

Comment: Re: "The definition of the function func() is present in the a.cpp file": is it appropriately marked up with `extern "C"`?

Comment: What is the compiler?

Comment: Do you mean that the definition of func() in a.cpp also needs to be enclosed with EXTERNC void func() { } as done in the a.h file? I didnt do that. But I tried marking the definition also with extern "C", even then it is giving the same error.

Comment: I have a hardware having Psos OS and the compiler is hcppc and compilation is done using makefiles(nmake).

Comment: As you're probably aware, those are pretty obscure products. How old is this system? And can you confirm which line of code is getting flagged with this error? (It's the `extern "C" declaration, right?)

Comment: Yes it flagging the error on the line: #define EXTERNC extern "C"

Comment: @Ashna No, `EXTERNC void func();` is the declaration I was talking about. It sounds like the entire file after `#ifdef __cplusplus` may be extraneous. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a complaint about C++ code in a C file. You *do* have a C file, so make sure that the conditional compilation is going the right way.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus

#ifdef COMING_FROM_B_C
#error __cplusplus is defined in inclusion from b.c
#endif

#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif

EXTERNC void func();
#undef EXTERNC
```

and in `b.c`

```
#define COMING_FROM_B_C 1
#include "a.h"
```

C compilers are forbidden from predefining `__cplusplus`, but something may have gone awry.

---

From what you have said so far, it sounds like the compiler stops at `#ifdef __cplusplus`.
Try compiling a C file containing only

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#error problem
#else
#error OK
#endif
```

This should flag an error on the line "OK." If it does anything else, the compiler is (very) defective.

Comment: I tried adding #ifdef COMING_FROM_B_C macro in a.h and defined COMING_FROM_B_C as 1 in b.c, and I am getting the same C++ feature not enabled error which means that conditional compilation is probably going in the correct order. To be more clear, the compiler is hcppc.

Comment: @Ashna This code isn't a solution, it's a diagnostic. The question is whether the compiler flagged the `#error` line.

Comment: I compiled a C file containing only the snippet you mentioned in your edited answer and the compiler flags an error on the line "OK".

Comment: @Ashna Then the compiler should be OK. Perhaps some header has a `#define __cplusplus` somewhere. Try and narrow it down by deduction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem was not in extern "C"declaration. Infact the arguments which were getting passed had C++ default values. For eg: EXTERNC void func(
   int a,const char* msg = NULL,...); This declaration is not supported in C. And niether is "..." ( ellipses) supported. Conversion of default value is easy but how to get rid of ellipses as this function is called in numerous places and different number of arguments are passed everywhere.

Comment: C does have ellipses, but only if there's another argument. For example `void fn(int,...)` is OK but not `void fn(...)`. Anyway, it looks like you wasted my time by posting code that *didn't* produce your problem.